# How to check if a Cell contains a dropdown list with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a VBA Scribt, that automatlically fills a large Excle with dummy data for testing reasons. 
Therefore i traverse all used cells and check theyr NumberFormat.
The Excel also contains dropdown lists.

Is there any function that can find/ identify such a list and automatically select a random value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to check a cell for *DataValidation*

```
Sub IsIt()
    On Error GoTo trap
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
trap:
    MsgBox "no data validation"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```